# Extracting emails from a string containing multiple emails?

Tags: reactjs

I have created a component which has `email`, `subject` and `message` input fields. My objective is to add and send email to multiple recipients which is separated by a comma. But it's not working.

In Console, I could see that it is taking multiple recipient into one string like this

```
"abc@yahoo.com, ert@gmail.com, werty@yahoo.com"
```

But i want the string to be formatted this way

```
"abc@yahoo.com", "ert@gmail.com", "werty@yahoo.com"
```

for example: i want to send an email to 3 recipients:
`abc@yahoo.com`, `ert@gmail.com`, `werty@yahoo.com`

Anyone can help me in this please. Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you intend to solve is that you have a field for `email`, `subject` and `message` which the user enters data to send the email with subject `subject` and message `message` to all the emails provided in the field `email`.

There are a number of ways to solve this problem depending on how you format your user input for the `email` field. The **simplest** way would be to accept emails(s) separated by a space. E.g. if user needs to send the email to the 3 emails `abc@abc.com`, `bcd@bcd.com` and `cde@cde.com` then you accept them all in one string where each email is separated by a space.

```
"abc@abc.com bcd@bcd.com cde@cde.com"
```

Now you can extract all the emails in your `email` string by simply calling `email.split(" ")`

```js
const email = "abc@abc.com bcd@bcd.com cde@cde.com";
const emails = email.split(" ");

console.log(emails);
// ["abc@abc.com","bcd@bcd.com","cde@cde.com"]
```

So your modified `handleSubmit` method would be something like this

```
handleSubmit = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const { email, subject, message } = this.state;
    const email_list = email.split(" ");
    const data = {
      email: email_list,
      subject,
      message
    };

    axios
      .post(`/api/email`, data, {
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" }
      })
      .then(res => {
        console.log(res);
        console.log(res.data);
      })
      .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
      });
  };
```

You also need to change your `changeHandle` method like this

```
changeHandle = e => this.setState({[e.target.name]: e.target.value });
```

This is the simplest way to accept multiple emails. You can devise any method you feel works for your app. The method described above is probably the most straightforward way I could think of. Feel free to drop a comment if you need further clarifications

Comment: @GiddharthSuptha - Hi, Your Solution is really nice but i'm facing problem with handle change method(when i try to enter email, it is getting separated by comma but when i paste email it is not diving each letter in bits and pieces) and if i give "abc@abc.com, bcd@bcd.com" then in console i could see it is taking as `"abc@abc.com,", "bcd@bcd.com"`

Comment: @Chandan I have updated the answer. Please check and accept if this solves your problem